# WhatsApp business api бот

Tags: api, whatsapp

Пишу бота сразу на несколько месенджеров Telegram, Viber и WhatsApp , если первые двое имеют документацию то с вацапом дело обстоит не понятно. Я нашел информацию на офф. сайте вацап о Whatsapp business api, но я не нашел примеров реализации бота на нем. И есть сервис twilio которые предоставляют апи к вацапу. Подскажите, будет ли достаточно воспользоваться  Whatsapp business api что-бы пайтоном принимать и обрабатывать сообщения или же нужно подключать сторонние сервесы?